# What does "he had a nasty look about him" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> "I always thought he had a nasty look **about him**,..."

I don't know what "*about him*" is doing in this sentence. I feel "*he had a nasty look*" is fairly enough. What additional information does "*about him*" add?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an idiomatic usage of about usually found referring to the qualities of someone or something:

***[About](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/about)***:

> When you say that there is a particular quality about someone or something, ***you mean that they have this quality.***
>
> - *There was a warmth and passion about him I never knew existed.*
> - *I think there's something a little peculiar about the results of your test.*

(Collins Dictionary)

***[About:](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/about)***

> used when referring to qualities that someone or something has:
>
> - One thing I like about Tony, he always says exactly what he thinks.
> - There was something about her that made him uneasy.

(Macmillan Dictionary)